# How to add another linked list objects

Tags: java, linked-list

I a homework where I need to merge two linkedlist, "songs" list and "artists" linked list, it works on the first list the "song" list, but whenever i add another list it just wont work
[as you can see  here the public static void now has errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNmTa.png)

```
package mergedlinkedlist;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Mergedlinkedlist {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       LinkedList<String>song = new LinkedList<>();
           song.add("imagine");
           song.add("bohemian rhapsody");
           song.add("highway to hell");
           
           System.out.println(song);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       LinkedList<String>artists = new LinkedList<>();
           artists.add("john lennon");
           artists.add("queen");
           artists.add("ACDC");
           
           System.out.println(artists);
}
```

Comment: You cannot have two `main` functions in the same file

Comment: Plus, you are missing a closing `}` on the 2nd `main()`.

Comment: You can't have two methods with the same name and parameters. Declare artists list in the same method (rather than in another method) that song is. Then you can use song.addAll(artists) to add all elements of artists to song list.

Comment: got the second linked list now thanks. is song.addAll(artists) another moethod or i will just put in with the same method?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, as one comment has pointed out, no program can have 2 main methods. You cannot create another one.
I suggest to integrate the code from your second into your first. You can safely just add the contents together.

The task is to merge the lists. Do you need any more help with that?

Assuming the task says you know the size of the list you can just create a new list and use the same method you used above to add them to the list. If you do not, you will need to use a loop. It would look like this:

```
LinkedList<String>artistsAndSongs = new LinkedList<>();

        if (artists.size() == songs.size()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < artists.size(); i++) {
                artistsAndSongs.add(artists.get(i));
                artistsAndSongs.add(songs.get(i));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not every artist is matched with a song!");
        }
```

But you should read up on how linked lists work exactly in the documentation. This will not only improve your understanding of the class but also teach you how to quickly find solutions to your problem.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hey GalliadII, so i managed to add another linked list, my problem now is how to merge those two linked lists using the addll() method, but it shows errors, how to merge those two linked lists?

the output should be like this:

song- artist
song- artist
song-artist

TIA

Comment: I edited the answer. Tell me if it works out for you, ok?